# mat-list arrange by under same category and heading should come once

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a mat-list and I am displaying category and name with data in it. Please note the stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-krzxrz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

What I need is to arrange is so that the category `Fruits` comes as heading with the fruit names under it, and then the same with `vegetables`.

Comment: Do you want a tree structure or a table structure look like? It is not clear what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Comment: I mean mat tree arrange by heading . Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to achieve is display each item of a category under a header with that category name, a possible approach is to group your array of object (`simpleItems`) by name and then use the `keyvalue` pipe to print the key followed by the elements.

[Here's a Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-v25w1l).

Hope this helps.